# $y^{\prime} = (-x-y+2)^2, y(0) = 1$

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

$y^{\prime} = (-x-y+2)^2, y(0) = 1$

My ideas:

$ u = -x -y +2$

$u^{\prime} = -1 -y^{\prime}$

$u^{\prime}  = -u^2 -1$

I dont know how to solve this differential equation because of the $-1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$u'  = -u^2 -1$$
It's separable:
$$\int \dfrac {du} {u^2 +1}=-\int dx$$
And you have that:
$$\int \dfrac {du}{u^2+1}=\arctan u+C$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! so in my case: $y = -x - \tan(-x+\pi / 4) +2 $

Comment: You're welcome. Yes that looks correct to me. @maria99